# jQuery serialize() not working on Ajax-loaded dialogues in IE

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm hoping someone on this site can offer some help. I have a page that uses ajax to load a form (id: "editform") into a jQuery-ui dialog box. The dialog box has a button attached - when someone changes the form and clicks this button it triggers a function which `serialize()`s the form data and sends it via `$.post` to replace a div on the page with the results. This works fine in every browser I've tested on except...wait for it...IE (all versions). The problem seems to be that IE is not recognizing the call to serialize this form.

```
alert($("#editform").serialize());
```

gives me "" in IE, but the desired long querystring in other browsers. I've also tried to grab the data one piece at a time,

```
alert($("#name").val());
```

Again - IE does not recognize this field, returning "" while the other browsers output the data I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: both your examples work fine for me ... what jquery version ? sure you do not have duplicate IDs ? or any IE conditional comments that might do something bad to jquery ? (*btw your example is missing the ending `)` for the 1st alert... just in case..*)

Comment: can you show the relevant html markup? maybe even the function in which you call `.serialize`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay - I found it. Thanks, Brandon H. for pointing me to the HTML - I hadn't closed the form () in the generated HTML, which was apparently tripping up IE. I got it up and running now.

Thanks all for your time.

Comment: Ran into the same thing.  For me an unclosed <p> tag earlier on the page was causing some (but not all) fields to be left out from the serialized form.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a typo in here, or also in your code:

```
alert($("#editform").serialize();
```

See the missing `)`. It should be:

```
alert($("#editform").serialize());
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - that was just a typo here - not a copy/paste job. I've been using the correct code, which works in non-IE browsers.